# Strange results with POSIX RegEx in Xcode

Tags: c++, regex, xcode, posix

I just switched to the built-in regex functionality using regex.h (to be cross platform). And with the following simple regex, many valid inputs, such as **as@abc.com** now fail (where **ab@abc.com** still works fine):

```
^[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^\s\.@]+$
```

The calling code is:

```
return Common::regexMatch("^[^@\\s]+@[^@\\s]+\\.[^\\s\\.@]+$", userInput);
```

And here's the implementation:

```
#import "regex.h"

bool Common::regexMatch(const string& regex, const string& text) {
   //return [[NSString stringWithCString:text.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] isMatchedByRegex:[NSString stringWithCString:regex.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

   regex_t re = {0};
   if (regcomp(&re, regex.c_str(), REG_NOSUB | REG_EXTENDED | REG_ICASE) != 0)
      return false;
   int status = regexec(&re, text.c_str(), (size_t)0, NULL, 0);
   regfree(&re);
   if (status != 0)
      return false;
   return true;   
}
```

It's baffling that it's discriminating based on a different letter, when the regex pattern has no letter specifications in it at all.  And it's very consistent on which inputs it doesn't like.  TIA.

Comment: Since it is `s` that is failing you, I suppose it's a problem with the escaping. Try replacing the double backslashes with single ones. Also, there is no need to escape the period inside a character class. Ever.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply, that was super helpful. It turns out POSIX Extended doesn't support escaping the space character, but is just fine with literal spaces, so I replaced all of the "\\s" with " " and it fired right up!

Comment: note that `\s` has a different meaning than a single space. `\s` is equivalent to `[\t\n\r ]`. So it matches any kind of whitespace. also, feel free to post the solution to your question as an answer and accept it. that's perfectly valid, if you've found the problem yourself.

Comment: I just found this great post http://stackoverflow.com/a/400316/497357 that with POSIX Extended syntax, you cannot escape ANY characters within a character class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out POSIX Extended doesn't support escaping the space character, but is just fine with literal spaces, so I replaced all of the "\s" with " " and it fired right up.

For more info, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/400316/497357